# Real Business Case - booking sales FCST - linear trend or polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm dealing with a real business case for my company and I'm trying to figure out if there's a math formula/model that can help me.
Let me explain the issue.

We're selling a product through a booking campaign, collecting orders that will be delivered in March (31st). We have 10.000 clients which we will sell to. Our Sales Agents, from now til March 30, will be collecting these orders. The aim is to monitor the daily amount of orders to forecast a final number.

I was thinking the most obvious trend would be a linear one, so that:

Date         16-oct - 17-oct - 19-oct........30 March

Total Orders               500   ,   700   ,   1000 ......... 150.000

Number of client reached: 25    ,   75    ,     150.......... 10.000

That's why I was thinking that the formula would be y=mx+c ->

Total amount of orders collected = (average orders collected each day)*(numbers of niew client reached) + total amount of orders at previous day

However, as we reach the total number of client (10.000), I expect the average orders collected each day decreases. In this case,the trend should be linear in a first moment but it should slightly decrease reaching a plateau when all the clients have been contacted for the sale. I'm wondering that the model should be a polynomial of some order, but I'm struggling to define the formula.

I'd really appreciate if you can share your thoughts about this, would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot,
David

Comment: Hard to say much without a lot more information.  Forecasting models are notoriously unreliable and every situation has its own complicating factors.  Lots of things might, for instance, make this non-linear.  Word of mouth, budget cycles in the purchasing firms, and so on.  Hard to guess which factors are relevant to your case.

Comment: May be worth noting:  firms in such a position often offer discounts to "early adopters".  Getting orders in early helps the firm out and reduces uncertainty, so offering a modest discount can sometimes make sense.  Beyond that...well, it often comes down to cost of  excess inventory and things like that.

Comment: I totally agree with you. In this case in my opinion what is helpful is that we have a booking window with a fixed number of clients (will be exactly 10k clients). What is making a difference is the average quantity of daily orders collected. No promo/discount, conditions are the same for all the clients and the stock in trade is basically at the same level for all the clients.